# Unit voltage template method for the control of D-statcom

Tags: matlab, simulink, pid-controller

I have got this model of the D-statcom which I am trying to implement from this paper [Analysis of shunt active powerfilter with unit template method](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1109/ICCPEIC.2017.8290463)

I have created a model as show below [image: d-statcom as Active power filter]

The controller set up is show below .

[image]

No matter what i do the dc value is not matching the refrence value (no matter what the value of PI controller) .

The complete model can be downloaded from here [MATLAB MODEL OF D-statcom](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j1fw4IhKiII5usQc6-ZAEbYLLDD01KyL/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0):

The error was in taking the error signals . Had to interchange them and voila .

In case anyone faced this problem (as this model is not on the internet).Kindly reach me here .

Thank you